# Slingshot fail to upload to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, meteor, meteor-slingshot, react-slingshot

Slingshot package is used with Meteor to upload images to S3 directly from the client. Same code that I've used in other projects approved to be working. Even a**t my local setup, I can upload images to cloud, but not with its deployed version, which is identical**. The error is as follows:

`Failed to upload file to cloud storage [Bad Request - 400]`

`the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'eu-central-1'`
(but it doesn't tell where...)

Any ideas?

This is the initialisation of the Meteor Slingshot directive:

```
const s3Settings = Meteor.settings.private.S3settings;
Slingshot.createDirective("userProfileImages", Slingshot.S3Storage, {
  AWSAccessKeyId: s3Settings.AWSAccessKeyId,
  AWSSecretAccessKey: s3Settings.AWSSecretAccessKey,
  bucket: s3Settings.AWSBucket,
  region: s3Settings.AWSRegion,
  acl: "public-read",

  authorize: function () {
    if (!this.userId) {
      const message = "Please login before posting images";
      throw new Meteor.Error("Login Required", message);
    }
    return true;
  },

  key: function (file) {
    const user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
    return user.username + "/" + file.name;
  }
});
```

This is my Amazon S3 CORS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>10000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I have no bucket policy.
Access control is all public.

Help appreciated.

Comment: how are you configuring the s3 client?

Comment: @DanielA.White Like noted in this below link, I add them to the `createDirective` method. I did have the region there as well... And like I said before, it works locally.
https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot#add-meta-context-to-your-uploads

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: This is probably an error in the S3 client configuration, not a CORS error. Can you post your S3 client initialization code?

Comment: I just added it. Please note that the upload works flawlessly on my local setup, which is identical to what I deploy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was me. I defined the region in my settings as `AWSregion` (`r`), whereas I called it `AWSRegion` (`R`) in my code to setup. So it was undefined and didn't work.

The solution is to make sure cases are typed right.